# Plugins folder during sonar upgrade

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

What is a good way for extension/plugins during sonar upgrade? I am upgrading sonar from 4.0 to 4.5.1 second time.In first time, I copied the old extension/plugins folder into new sonar version.It so happened that during first time, there was a C# plugins and during database upgrade step, we got the message of "Impossible to upgrade Database". On removing this plugin, the database upgrade didn't happen and we were taken directly to the login page. As a results projects were missing on sonar dashboard though the LDAP users got imported.So I would like to know what is the right way out of below ?
1. Copy the old plugins folder from sonar 4.0 (old) folder to sonar 4.5.1 (new) folder. 
2. Don't copy the old plugin folder. Just download the new plugins which are required post sonar upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't* do #2! It will screw up your rule profiles.

You started out correctly by copying the plugins folder. But you have to go a little farther.

You need to read the upgrade notes for each intervening version. They're all children of [this general guide to upgrading](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading). They should mention all plugin incompatibilities & you'll have to deal with those manually. You may be able to do some of the upgrades via the update center in the old version before you shut it down. The rest you have to handle by deleting/replacing the old plugin jars.